# Thread lifetime in linux

Tags: linux, pthreads

Currently I'm trying to understand what happens when a shared library spawns a thread, which does not terminate and the shared library is then unloaded.

What happens to the thread if the parent does not wait for the thread to exit?
Does the thread die or does it remain in the running state?

If it does then how can the parent detect when it's being unloaded and somehow terminate the thread?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the shared library is some plugin dynamically loaded at runtime using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and later explicitly unloaded using `dlclose`.

The `dlopen` and `dlclose` functions are internally using a reference counter and they are [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ing (for `dlopen`) and `munmap`-ing (for `dlclose`) some segments inside the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object when appropriate (i.e. when the ref counter crosses the 0 border).

If a thread is running some function inside the `dlclose`-d shared library, the code of that function becomes `munmap`-ed and as soon as you jump (or return into) that function, you get a SIGBUS, SIGILL or SIGSEGV signal.

So you don't want that `munmap`to happen: hence you could:

1. avoid calling `dlclose`; this works very well in practice (unless you have a server program), because `mmap` consumes mostly address space for text read-only segments of shared object. As my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) demonstrates, you can `dlopen` hundreds of thousands of shared objects on a desktop without reaching serious limits.
2. or pass `RTLD_NODELETE` to `dlopen` asking it to never unmap the library

Alternatively, use some facilities (i.e. [destructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)-attributed functions in the shared library) or conventions (perhaps [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)?) to be sure that the thread has ended before `dlclose`

Comment: The shared library is loaded using PRELOAD and it's job is to override samba calls so I think the shared library is loaded by samba and I never call dlopen or dlclose.  So how can the library detect when it's about to be unloaded?

Comment: Use destructor functions, or finalizers, .... AFAIK `PRELOAD`-ed shared objects are unloaded very late, perhaps after normal `exit`.

Comment: Tried the destructor version and that worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shared library is loaded into process, so spawn thread will run in process address space.

Thread will keep running if not noticed to exit. and when process is exit, thread will also be terminated.

As shared library spawn the thread, so it is better that shared library also provide a function which will notice thread to exit so process can call the function to exit thread before unload library.